# toggle visibility for dynamically created html button with jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I am new to web development... am creating an html table using jsp.  (within spring for those interested)

```
<tbody>
<c:forEach var="row" items="${data.rows}">
   <tr>
      <td>  <c:out value="${row.DATA1}" />  </td>
      <td>  <c:out value="${row.DATA2}" />  </td>
      <td class="formClass" title="click to edit...">  
          <form> 
            <input type="text" name="DATA" value="${row.DATA}"> 
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form> 
      </td>
      <td>  <c:out value="${row.DATA3}" />  </td>

       </tr>
   </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

The issue is, that I want to have the submit button be invisible until the person clicks on the textarea.  I have no idea how many rows there will be, because that comes from a database, so I can't just assign an ID to each of the submit buttons.

How would I do this?  If possible I'd like to fit the solution onto the .jsp file before creating separate css or js to link to

Comment: "so I can't just assign an ID to each of the submit buttons." Why not? There's no unique id in the database? You can't use a for loop rather than foreach (i.e. so you have an index)?  Of course you can assign an id to the submit buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do, is to bind an `focus` event to all of your text input elements. Inside the event function `this` will refer to the input that triggered the event. Because the inputs are siblings, you can use `siblings` selector to show the sibling submit button of that specific text input.

So here's the code:

```
// before using jQuery, you have to wait for the dom to be ready
$(document).ready(function () {

    // bind an focus event to all the text inputs
    $('input[type="text"]').on('focus', function () {

        // inside this function, $(this) is referring to the input that triggered the event
        $(this).siblings('input[type="submit"]').fadeIn();

    });

});
```

You could also use `.show()` instead of `.fadeIn()` if you like.

Remember to hide the submit buttons first with css:

```
input[type="submit"] {
    display: none;
}
```

or jQuery:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').hide();
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zmr5ytrk/1/

Comment: thanks for the commented code!  Makes a difference

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I have to add that `next()` could a better method for selecting the sibling, because it only looks for the next sibling  of the text input. In your case it makes no difference really, but some may consider it a better code.

Comment: I'm running into another issue... This particular table is actually displayed using jQuery Datatables.. and everything is working when I first load the page... but then If I select to view 50 rows instead of 25 on datatables then it does not work for the second 25... I suspect its related to the bind happening before those 25 rows are displayed... any suggestions?

Comment: Try using delegated event handler like this: `$('form').on('focus', 'input[type="text"]', function() { ... });`. It binds the click event (also) for the elements added after the page load.

Comment: hmm that didn't seem to do it http://jsfiddle.net/zmr5ytrk/10/ if you try any of the first 10 it will work... but if you click to show 25 and then try the next ones it doesnt work

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Datatables, so I don't know why, but changing the first selector from `form` to `table` or `body` seems to fix the issue. I forked your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zmr5ytrk/12/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65401/discussion-between-ben-and-balzafin).

Answer (score 1):

Simply use jQuery to do that.

First you must define classes or ids on your forms `<form class="CLASSNAME">` .

Then try this:

```
$('.CLASSNAME').each(function(){
    var form_elements=$(this.elements); //gets all elements that belong to this form
    var form = $(this);
    form_elements.each(function(){
        var element = $(this); 
        if(element.attr('type')!="submit"){ //exclude the button type
            element.on('focus', function(){ //add focus handler that will trigger when you click on an element
                form.find('input[type="submit"]').fadeIn(); //shows the button
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Don't forget to set your submit buttons to `display:none;` on your CSS, the `fadeIn()` function will set it back to `display:block;`

**NOTE:** This will work for every form that has a class `.CLASSNAME`!

Comment: This seems overly complicated. I get that you may only want to target certain forms, but you don't need to loop through them, just add that condition to your jQuery selector. Also, the inner loop could be avoided with better selectors--it makes for cleaner code.

Comment: Yes i do want to target forms with a certain class name, but also their children so i can perform an action on each form diferently.

Comment: The result works, I just prefer to see a shorter syntax--this is what jQuery does really well. Your code can be exactly duplicated with the following two lines: `$('.CLASSNAME').children().not('input[type="submit"]').on('focus', function() {$(this).next('input[type="submit"]').fadeIn();});`. Excuse the formatting but you can see it better in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1pdq2kc3/)

Comment: True story there, i tend to use less selectors as possible. In this particular case `$('.CLASSNAME').children()` you are setting `on('focus')` to unnecessary elements, even if it will never trigger. My method works for the kind of work i do. thanks any way for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to change your HTML at all, this is pretty simple using jQuery. First, hide all the `submit` elements on your page. Then when your input is focused, find the next `submit` sibling and show it.

Here's a simple runnable example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type="submit"]').hide();
});

$('input[type="text"]').on('focus', function() {
  $(this).next('input[type="submit"]').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>DATA1</td>
      <td>DATA2</td>
      <td class="formClass" title="click to edit...">  
          <form> 
            <input type="text" name="DATA" value="row.DATA"> 
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form> 
      </td>
      <td>DATA3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>DATA1</td>
      <td>DATA2</td>
      <td class="formClass" title="click to edit...">  
          <form> 
            <input type="text" name="DATA" value="row.DATA"> 
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form> 
      </td>
      <td>DATA3</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```